# What are the Pager and Hash plugins for lightGallery?

Tags: lightgallery

I came across the Pager and Hash plug-ins for lightGallery: http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightgallery1.2/docs/api.html#lg-pager

The docs tell how to enable them. But what are they for? What's their use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the pager displays the 'current-image/total-images' in the upper left corner (ex. 4/34 on the fourth item).

The hash plug-ins creates unique URL's with hash(#) id's for every item(slide=) of the gallery or galleries(lg=).

Example: www.foo.com/bar/foobar.php#lg=1&slide=0.
Where 'lg=1' refers to the first gallery and 'slide=0' refers to the first item inside that (lg=1) gallery. Every item has it's own unique URL.

Comment: And also adds some dots which collide with the slider. This is not a "pagination" like i thought.